# url for img tag in ajax loaded html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm loading an html file with jQuery's get method, and placing the whole body content into the DOM, again with jQuery.

There are lots of img tags inside this html content that I'm loading.

For instance,

```
<img src="warning.png">
```

warning.png is in the same directory with the html file on the server.

The directory structure on the server is like this

```
/myapp/myfolder/content.html
/myapp/myfolder/warning.png
```

On a mobile browser with LTE connection, the images inside this html content cannot be loaded.

However, when I change the src attribute of the img element to an absolute url as you can see below

```
<img src="/myapp/myfolder/warning.png">
```

the image is always loaded properly no matter what connection I'm using. (LTE / 3G / wifi / whatever)

I can of course replace src attribute for every single img element with an absolute value. However, it becomes a maintenance hell after a while, for sure.

I think this has something to do with the relationship between the connection speed and the async loading of the html content from the server.

Does anybody have any idea about this?

Comment: probably has to do with you loading html into page with different directory. Path is no longer valid. it's not where the file resides that's important, it's where the file gets consumed

Comment: Problemo is in response of url you are hitting. Show code of the service which returns image url.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @charlietfl That's right, where the file gets consumed matters. It works fine if I'm not connected via LTE even though I'm using an incorrect url . That's still a mystery, but not part of the problem anymore. Maybe that has something to do with browser cache, anyway, thanks again

Comment: @charlietfl you can post it as an answer if you like so that I'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a javascript function that would automatically change the image URL for you, which would save you the hassle of manually updating the urls by yourself:

```
$("img").each(function(img){
    $(this).attr("src", "/myapp/myfolder/"+ $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

You would call this function at the bottom of your page. Simply include it in your master page (or a shared include file). If your images aren't all in one folder, I would suggest modifying the function to be aware of what your current URL is and change "/myapp/myfolder/" appropriately.

I don't know enough about mobile browser kinks to comment on the why, but changing the links to an absolute path is good practice anyway.